# Not able to compare the passwords in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a scenario where I am trying to check if the parameterised password value (which is entered while executing the pipeline) is equal or same as the password stored in credentials manager.

```
def ex(param){
    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
    error('BAD PARAM: ' + param)
}
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        password(name: 'key', description: 'Encryption key')
    }   

    stages { 
        stage("check params") {
            steps {
                withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'api_key', variable: 'api_key')]) {
                script {
                    
                    if ("${params.key}" != "$api_key") {ex("key")}
                    
                }
            }
            }
        }
}
}
}
```

I tried comparing these values in different ways like

if ('${params.key}' != '$api_key') {ex("key")}

if ("${params.key}" != env.api_key) {ex("key")}

and so on

The credentials I am providing as parameters are correct.
If I check passwords by providing static value, it works properly
Ex

if ('${params.key}' != "my_secret_value") {ex("key")}

I tried lot of ways but nothing is working for me and I am not able to figure it out what's the issue and how will I able to check the if condition and compare the password.

I am troubleshooting this from a longer time.
Please help me out with this
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Confirm the credential type in Jenkins is `Secret Text`, otherwise if its type is `Username and password (conjoined)` or `Username and password (separated)`, you should use `withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'amazon', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')])`

Comment: I am sure I have used credential type as Secret Text

Comment: If Python installed, you can add following step to check the secret in credential is correct `sh 'echo $api_key | python -c "import sys; print(list(sys.stdin.read()))"'`